# How to generate three unequal numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, jvm, set

Here the number generation :

```
for( int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    int randomNumbers = random.nextInt(10) + 1; 
}
```

And here I can receive the same digits.

For example: `5,7,5`;

But I need to receive only different numbers: `5,1,9`.

Is it possible maybe with some little piece of code or I should write some method for it?

Comment: Do a while loop instead and check if you have already generated that number. If not, increase your counter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `Set` which holds only unique values:

```
Set<Integer> randomInts = new HashSet();
while(randomInts.size() < 3) {
    randomInts.add(random.nextInt(10) + 1);
}
```

Of course, you need to face oversampling, but this approach scales very easily if performance isn't the most important.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way that avoids [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling): generate one number up to 10, one up to 9, and up to 8. Avoid repeats by incrementing. This guarantees a uniform distribution.

```java
int a = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
int b = random.nextInt(9) + 1;
if(b >= a) { b++; }
int c = random.nextInt(8) + 1;
if(c >= (a > b ? b : a)) { c++; }
if(c >= (a > b ? a : b)) { c++; }
```

Comment: Bit shorter, not sure if better or worse: `c >= a || c >= b` and `c >= a && c >= b`.

Answer (score 2):

In my point of view, using a while loop is possible to generate random numbers with different digits. Use while loop to check whether the number was generated earlier and if it was then generate new number.